# Spring XML to object mapping returns "Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=..."

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an endpoint (`GET localhost:8080/api/getPerson`), which should map the request body into an object. It works well when I send a body as JSON but when sending a XML I get a Unsupported Media Type (415) back.

```java
package com.example.xml2object;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class Example {

  @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person")
  public static class Person {
    public String name;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "getPerson")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(person.name);
  }
}
```

When calling the `/api/getPerson` with e.g. Postman using `Content-Type: application/json` the response is as expected `alice`:

```json
{
    "name": "alice"
}
```

However, when sending a request as `Content-Type: application/xml` a 415 is returned.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person>
    <name>alice</name>
</person>
```

Responds with:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-01-23T17:43:40.290+00:00",
    "path": "/api/getPerson",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=com.example.xml2object.Example$Person",
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try put the correct Content Type inside your @GetMapping "consume". Example:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "getPerson", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<String> getPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(person.name);
  }
}
```

the class MediaType is from the package: org.springframework.http.MediaType